# What are the differences between Linux filesystem, Linux server data, Linux root, Linux reserved and Linux home in fdisk?

Tags: filesystems, fdisk, cfdisk

While creating file systems with fdisk on GPT partitions, I have noticed in the file system type, there are options like:

```
 20 Linux filesystem               0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
 21 Linux server data              3B8F8425-20E0-4F3B-907F-1A25A76F98E8
 22 Linux root (x86)               44479540-F297-41B2-9AF7-D131D5F0458A
 23 Linux root (ARM)               69DAD710-2CE4-4E3C-B16C-21A1D49ABED3
 24 Linux root (x86-64)            4F68BCE3-E8CD-4DB1-96E7-FBCAF984B709
 25 Linux root (ARM-64)            B921B045-1DF0-41C3-AF44-4C6F280D3FAE
 26 Linux root  (IA-64)             993D8D3D-F80E-4225-855A-9DAF8ED7EA97
 27 Linux reserved                 8DA63339-0007-60C0-C436-083AC8230908
 28 Linux home                     933AC7E1-2EB4-4F13-B844-0E14E2AEF915
 29 Linux RAID                     A19D880F-05FC-4D3B-A006-743F0F84911E
```

I have used Linux filesystem, Linux root (x86_x4), Linux home on my systems interchangeably with XFS, NilFS, EXT4 and ReiserFS.

What are the difference between these file system types? Is there a man page documenting all of them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table you can follow the links in footnotes 34 and 35 to find explanations.

https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/DiscoverablePartitionsSpec/

https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd-gpt-auto-generator.html

The main purpose of the different types is to allow automatic mounting of certain partitions to the correct location in your file system.

Comment: footnotes 34 and 35 link to microsoft docs now

Answer (score 2):

[Arch wiki suggests](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fdisk#Change_partition_type):

> When using GPT, it is advised to follow the [Discoverable Partitions Specification](https://https://uapi-group.org/specifications/specs/discoverable_partitions_specification/) since systemd-gpt-auto-generator can automount them. I.e. use Linux root (x86-64) for the root partititon, Linux swap for the swap partition, Linux home for the home partition and so on.